# How can I use multiple delimiters (',' , '/n') with getline()?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a text file in my code using fstream. The text file has the following structure,

```
Main,Johnsons,4,4
Lake,Smiths,1,2
Orchid,Hendersons,3,8
```

I am trying to do the following.

```
Neighborhood n1;
ifstream houses;
houses.open("houses.txt");
string line;

string street;
string family;
int house;
int rooms;

int colptr = 1;

while (houses.good()) {
   getline(houses, line, ',');

        switch (colptr) {
        case 1: {
            col1 = line;
            colptr++;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            col2 = line;
            colptr++;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            col3 = stoi(line);
            colptr++;
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            col4 = stoi(line);
            colptr = 1;
            House h(col1, col2, col3, col4);
            n1.addHouse(h);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            break;
        }
        }
    }
```

House is a class that takes (string,string,int,int) to construct a House, and the method addHouse() of the Neighborhood class just adds the House to a list of houses.

The code throws an error because it is trying to convert a string to int. I caught that on the 4 iteration it will try to convert "4 Lake" to an integer - which it obviously can't do.

The code works if if format my text file with a ',' at the end like

```
Main,Johnsons,4,4,
```

Except this won't work for me because the text file I'm given is always like the one shown at the beginning.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of trying to do it with one loop, use two: one to read lines from the file, and one to split each line into columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `getline()` twice in a nested loop. First one reads input typically "line by line", the second one splits by the comma "," with assistance of a `std::stringstream` object:

```
//...
while (houses.good()) {
    getline(houses, line); //use default getline() - line by line
    std::stringstream ss (line);
    std::string word;
    while (getline (ss, word, ',')) {
        //... the rest of code
        //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the line and add the `,` char at the end, and then get the words.

```
while (houses.good()) {
   std::istringstream input;
   getline(houses, line);
   line += ',';
   input.str(line);
   for (std::string token; getline(input, token, ','); ) {
       // process words
   }
}
```